# NotFound component is not shown in build script

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My react app works well on localhost and when I try to access an url which is not in my app, the app automatically shows my NotFound component. However after build my app (with react-scripts build command) and put it into the hosting (I am not using Github pages), my NotFound component is not shown, the default 404 Not Found page is shown when I type wrong url.

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

app.js (render part)

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => (
            <div className="l">
              <div className="list-books-title">
                <h1>App</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="list-books-content">
                <BookShelf
                  title="Currently Reading"
                  books={this.state.currentlyReading}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                <BookShelf
                  title="Want to Read"
                  books={this.state.wantToRead}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                <BookShelf
                  title="Read"
                  books={this.state.read}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="open-search">
                <Link to="/search"> Add a Book</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        />

        <Route
          path="/search"
          render={() => (
            <Search
              searchQuery={this.state.query}
              updateQuery={this.updateQuery}
              searchedBooks={this.state.searchedBooks}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              filterChange={this.filterChange}
              allBooks={this.state.books}
            />
          )}
        />

        <Route render={() => (
          <NotFound />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is most likely because your web-server is not configured for single page applications. you need to tell your server always serve index.html regardless of the url.

from https://www.sej-ko.dk/2017/03/29/routing-single-page-application-on-apache-with-htaccess/

> You’ll have to tell Apache to rewrite everything to the index.html page, and let the single-page-application handle the routing. You do that like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: How can I do that? I think th server always serve the index.html first?

Comment: what server are you using

Comment: Linux, Apache server.